# target form to specific browser tab

Tags: browser, forms, tabs, target

Is there a cross-browser compatible way to post a form in one tab of the browser to another (which I know is open and is of the same domain)?

I tried `window.name='some_name';` and `target='some_name'` on the form, but this does not seem to work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard to how tabs are handled via javascript, so you are out of luck.

Most browsers these day also make sure each tab is segregated/partitioned from others, as much as possible, so this is unlikely to change in the recent future.

The closest you can get to posting to a different page is to use AJAX, or possibly using frames.